# yii search in double primary key table

Tags: php, yii, foreach, invalid-argument

I had to verify if there is a record in a table that has a double primary key.

```
$ssd=Ssd::model()->find(array(
                                'condition' => "id_scaglione=:sca AND COD_FIS LIKE :cf",
                                'params' => array(
                                                ':sca' => $sca_attivo->attributes['ID_SCAGLIONE'],
                                                ':cf' => $codfisc
                                            )
                            ));
```

but I have an "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" error.

I think is a problem of declared relationships in the models...

I have the same error with searching the primary key

```
$ssd = Scaglioni::model()->findByPk($sca_attivo->attributes['ID_SCAGLIONE'], $codfisc);
```

with the overriden method of the Ssd model:

```
public function primaryKey(){
    return array('ID_SCAGLIONE', 'COD_FIS');
}
```

---

Here the relationships of the models:

Scaglioni

```
class Scaglioni extends CActiveRecord{
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'ssd' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Ssd', 'ID_SCAGLIONE'),
        );
    }
}
```

Studenti

```
class Studenti extends CActiveRecord{
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'ssd' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Ssd', 'COD_FIS'),
            'scaglioni' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Scaglioni', array('ID_SCAGLIONE'=>'ID_SCAGLIONE'), 'through'=>'ssd'),

        );
    }
    }
```

Ssd

```
class Ssd extends CActiveRecord{
public function relations()
    {
        return array(               
            'scaglioni' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Scaglioni', 'ID_SCAGLIONE'),
            'studenti' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Studenti', 'COD_FIS'),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a multi-column PK you need to specify them using arrays. Your findByPk call will definitely not work the way you've posted it here.

Comment: Ok, Ssd::model()->findByPk is wrong, how I specify the multi column array? I have "public function primaryKey(){return array('ID_SCAGLIONE', 'COD_FIS');}" in the model.

Besides that why Ssd::model()->find doesn't work?

Comment: That is very hard to diagnose without at least a code location... That error can be pretty much caused by every foreach loop.

Comment: I think is generated from Ssd::model()->find(...) query, because if I comment it it works fine.

Comment: Probably yes, but we need to know where in the Yii code it fails. You should have a nice stack trace in your logs (or the output)

Comment: Posted the stack trace as answer

Answer (score 0):

It fails after the Ssd::model()->find(...) with a "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" error.

In particular:

```
/var/www/framework/db/schema/CDbCriteria.php(152)
 public function __construct($data=array())
{
foreach($data as $name=>$value)
$this->$name=$value;
}
```

The stack trace is:

0   /var/www/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php(316): CDbCriteria->__construct(null)

1   /var/www/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php(1338): CActiveRecord->getDbCriteria(false)

2   /var/www/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php(1281): CActiveRecord->applyScopes(CDbCriteria)

3   /var/www/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php(1392): CActiveRecord->query(CDbCriteria)

4   /var/www/concorsi/protected/controllers/ConfermaController.php(405): CActiveRecord->find(array("condition" => "id_scaglione=:sca AND COD_FIS LIKE :cf", "params" => array(":sca" => $sca_attivo->attributes['ID_SCAGLIONE'], ":cf" => $codfisc)))